# Is XMLHttpRequestObject.onreadystatechange... necessary?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm new to AJAX and I have a question like the title suggests. I mean if I only want to send data to server (to update the database etc.), but don't need the response text, I try to omit it .

```
XMLHttpRequestObject.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (XMLHttpRequestObject.readyState == 4 && XMLHttpRequestObject.status == 200) {
        // ...
    }
};
```

But it doesn't seem to work.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "doesn't work"?  What is it that fails?

Comment: So it can actually works? Well maybe my PHP script was wrong then ( it didn't update the database ). I will check it back.

Comment: Well it *might* work for you; we can't say because you don't say what went wrong.

Comment: I've had similar problems before. Make sure the file you're saving to has the permissions set properly.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to use the response data provided, but then there's no way you can be sure that the data was successfully sent, or received correctly, etc. Since you're not checking, you can omit your `onreadystatechange` definition.

This technique is called "beaconing". Since you do not need to check the response, it also means that you do not need to go through the hassle of making an XMLHTTPRequest (for only GET URLs, anyways):

```
var beacon = new Image();
beacon.src = "http://example.com/beacon.php?foo=10&bar=20";
```